# Cant run android app on my device

Tags: java, android, xml

I need help on running a SQLite app on a device.

I created an app which uses a database and it runs perfectly on my emulator.
It inserts and retrieves data without errors, but when I run it on my actual device it crashes.

I don't know what's the problem.
I am a beginner to android programming, so please tell me what the problem is?

I am testing on a Galaxy S5, if that changes anything.

Comment: Can you please post the logcat error messages?

Comment: like i said there is no error when i run it on emulator there is no error massage on the logcat it crushes when i run it on the device

Comment: The error from the device will give us a lot of information ;)

Comment: how can i get the error from the device it just displays "unfortunately MyApp has stopped" and closes

Comment: Fixed some grammar and formatting

Answer (score 0):

I would check minSdkVersion, targetSdkVersion, maxSdkVersion in your app and see if the version of Android in your phone is compatible